# ModuleNotFoundError though Python module PyBluez is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pybluez, modulenotfounderror

I am using python3 with the Thonny IDE. My programs are running on a Raspberry Pi 4B.

I tried to install PyBluez on different ways, with pip and with the built-in package installer of Thonny. Every time the installation seemed to work. When I then tried to import the module via `import PyBluez` I always get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybluez'
```

But when I try to install it again I get these message, what I think mean, that it is already installed:

```
 Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.4)
```

And the built-in package installer of Thonny shows me this message:

```
Installed version: 0.23
Installed to: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

Latest stable version: 0.23
Summary: Bluetooth Python extension module
Author: Albert Huang
Homepage: http://pybluez.github.io/
PyPI page: https://pypi.org/project/PyBluez/
Requires: pyobjc-core (<6,>=3.1), pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (<6,>=3.1), gattlib (==0.20150805) ; extra == 'ble'
```

But I still get the error that there is no module with this name.

I also tried to install the package PySerial on the same ways, but I ran into the same problem as with PyBluez. So it might be a general problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally worked with that module, but after looking at the GitHub documentation, I can see that the import statement that is used is `import bluetooth`.
For example, on this [page](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py) that's what they have

```
import bluetooth
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez
```

Consider using a different import statement

Comment: ok thank you 
I tried that out and this time no error pop up